# With cat command create a file which is a merge of 2 files(linux)

Tags: linux, cat

What I'm trying to do:

```
With cat command create a file named Merge which is the merge of
test.txt and Copy(in a different directory than test.txt)
```

Both `test.txt` and `Copy` contain the same content:

```
reglib
test.txt
```

So what I expect is:

```
reglib
test.txt
reglib
test.txt
```

What I've tried:

```
cat /home/eleve/Copy | cat test.txt >Merge.txt
cat /home/eleve/Copy >Merge.txt | cat test.txt >Merge.txt
cat /home/eleve/Copy >Merge.txt | cat test.txt >>Merge.txt
```

And all of those command gave me the same wrong result:

```
reglib
test.txt
```

Can anyone please suggest me the right command? thanks.

Comment: `cat` may take two arguments. `cat first_file second_file` will print both files.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks mate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "cat" on multiple files, in which case it'll print them out in order.

```
cat test.txt Copy
```

Comment: never knew it was so simple, thanks mate :)

Comment: "cat" is short for "concatenate", and it does indeed support concatenation :P